# js animate function scrolls to bottom of div instead of top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, jquery-animate

js windows animate scrolltop to div class is scrolling right to to the bottom of the div

js

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
   $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $('.tariff').offset().top
   }, 'slow');
});
```

it is scrolling right to the bottom of div class 'tariff'. I want it to scroll and stop at the top of the div.

Did a lot of googling. Don't know where I am going wrong.

**EDIT**

I think it may have something to do with my external js.js file. Something here is probably effecting the animate scrolling height. Because if I omit this file, 
it scrolls properly to the top of the div.

But I don't know what is interfering here.

js.js

```
    $('document').ready(function(){
    $('#smshare').click(function() {
        $('#smp').slideToggle('fast');
        $('#smp').load('social-media-share.php');
    });

    $('#offer,#orderlink').click(function()
    {
        $('#order').fadeIn('fast');
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#order").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    $('.scrolltop').fadeIn('fast');
    $('.aboutus,.tariff,.services,.contactus,.logged_order,.pers_dets,.clothes_submitted,.locations_list').fadeOut('fast');
    });

    $('.scrolltop').click(function(){
        $('#order').fadeOut('fast');
            $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".header").offset().top
        }, 2000);
            $('.scrolltop').fadeOut('fast');
    });

    $('#svl').click(function()
    {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".service_locations").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });

    $('.more1').click(function() {
        $('.more_dry_cleaning').slideToggle('fast');
    $('.more1').fadeOut('fast');
    });


    $('.less1').click(function() {
        $('.more_dry_cleaning').fadeOut('fast');
        $('.more1').fadeIn('fast');
    });


    var valid=0;
           $('form[name=orderform]').submit(function(e) { 
//                alert('Got you!');
            $('.clothesqty').each(function(){
//                alert('Got you!');
                        if($(this).val() != 0) {valid+=1;}
                    });

            if(valid!=0){
//                       e.preventDefault();
    //                  alert(valid + " inputs have been filled");
                        return true;
            }
            else {
                         e.preventDefault();
                        //alert('Houston we have contact!');
                        alert("error: you must fill in at least one field");
                        return false;
                    }
           });

                var oblen=Object.keys(item).length;
        var zero=0;

        var cloth = "";
        var i;
        var it=1;
        var totitems=0;
        var tot=0;
        var totcost=0;
        var itemid="";
        var itemclass="";
        var totval=0;

    for (var key in item) {
        if (!item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        //The current property is not a direct property of p
        continue;
        }
         var k=key;
         var v=item[key];

//       alert(v);
            cloth = k.replace(/ |-|&|\//g, '').toLowerCase();
             itemid="#" + cloth;
             itemclass="#" + cloth + "cost";
//           alert(v+"/"+itemid);

             $(itemid).keyup((function (id, cls,itm,val) {
                return function () {
                var x = $(id).val();
                if(x!=0){
                itemtot=x * val;
//              alert(itm+"->"+itemtot + "=" + x + "x" + val);
                $(cls).css("background-color", "#446666").css("padding","3px").css("color","white").css("width","60px").html("Rs." + itemtot);
                }else{
                $(cls).css("background-color", "#446666").css("padding","3px").css("color","white").css("width","60px").html("Rs." + zero);
                    }

                }

          } (itemid, itemclass,cloth,v)));
    }
        $("input").each(function() {
                    $(this).keyup(function(){
            //          calculateCost();
                        calculateSum();
                    });
                });
}); 

//Totals
function calculateSum() {
        var sum = 0;
        var totcost=0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $("input").each(function() {
            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0 && this.value.length<=3) {
                sum += eval(parseInt(this.value));
            }
        });

        $("div.ittot").each(function() {
            var tots=0;
            var str=$(this).text();
            var thenum = str.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
            var tots = parseInt(thenum,10);
            //add only if the value is number
            //if(!isNaN(tots) && tots.length!=0) {
            totcost += tots;
            //}
        });
//      alert(totcost);
    $("#totalcost").css("background-color", "green").html("<div style='float:left;margin-left:5px'><span style='font-weight:700'>Total Cost : </span>Rs."+ totcost + "</div><div style='float:right;margin-right:5px'><span style='font-weight:700'>Total Items : </span>" + sum + "</div><div style='clear:both'></div>");
}

//slider2
var myPicIndex = 0;
picCarousel();

function picCarousel() {
    var i;
    var x = getElementsByClassName("myPicSlides");

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    myPicIndex++;
    if (myPicIndex > x.length) {myPicIndex = 1}
    x[myPicIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(picCarousel, 3000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}

function getElementsByClassName(className) {
    var found = [];
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var names = elements[i].className.split(' ');
        for (var j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
            if (names[j] == className) found.push(elements[i]);
        }
    }
    return found;
}

//slider1

var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carousel, 3000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}

function getElementsByClassName(className) {
    var found = [];
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var names = elements[i].className.split(' ');
        for (var j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
            if (names[j] == className) found.push(elements[i]);
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I have further narrowed down the problem to the slider2 JS functions which seem to be a problem. Because if I remove the slider html which i have put in a slider2.php file and am including into the tariff.php file, then the scroll behaves properly.

slider2.php

```
<div style="width:100%;margin:0 auto">
    <img class="myPicSlides" src="images/header/clothes-drying-on-line-iv.jpg" alt="Laundry Clothes Drying">
    <img class="myPicSlides" src="images/header/new/shirts-on-line-iv.jpg" alt="Laundry Foam">
    <img class="myPicSlides" src="images/header/iron-and-clothes-iv.jpg" alt="Iron Clothes">
    <img class="myPicSlides" src="images/header/woollens-iv.jpg" alt="Woollens Laundry">
    <img class="myPicSlides" src="images/header/shirts-on-hanger-iv.jpg" alt="Laundry Shirts mylaundrywala">
</div>
```

**EDIT 3**

I believe the animate function is taking into consideration the heights of the images in the slider and adding them up ! How to resolve that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reach to the top of window, please use this:

```
$("html, body").animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
               }, 500);
```

$('.tariff').offset().top gives position distance between top of body and top of div with class "tariff".
As a result, it covers that much distance when scrolled.

Please try like this.

Comment: Thanks @Nitesh, but where do i specify the class 'tariff'  to target that div ?

Comment: Because if you observe my question, i want to scroll to top of div not window

Comment: @user3526204: OK, I didn't get question earlier.
Can you please check this fiddle. May be you want same?

https://jsfiddle.net/55wv758y/

Comment: it is not a click function. I am looking at auto scroll on page load. I tried your fiddle code widthout click event, but that also doesn't work. I have edited my question for more info. Please see.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
   $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $('.tariff').offset().top + $('.tariff').height()
   }, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: Still same result, Chetan. By the way, how is this supposed to do make the scroll stop at the top of the div ? Wont it further add the height ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the fiddle its is working for me there. Let me know if this helps.

`$("#scroll").click(function(e) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.tariff').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cw7m7z2u/)

Comment: There is no click event here, Nkt, it has to scroll on page load

Comment: Then you can just remove the click event it should work. Else share your code and we can help.

Comment: did it worked? are you having more than one `.tariff` elements by any chance?

Comment: Not working. The live page is here http://www.mylaundrywala.com/tariff . You can check the source code. I am using the above same code without click event.

Comment: Also happens on all pages

Answer (score 0):

Since I realized that it was the heights of the images in the slider which was being laid out one below the other by html rather than fading in and out one by one when javascript is called (which has a fractional delay), the animate function registers the page height including all the heights of the images ! And scrolls keeping those heights in consideration. That is why it was scrolling right down to the bottom. Instead of top of the div.

Though I was not able to find a js solution to the real problem, I managed to find a work around.

Finally, what I did was to delay the slider images loading by using 'load' function. And placed one static image there till slider loaded  and then faded the static image out after slider images loaded.

During this period, the animate function picks up only the height of that one static image which is actually the height that div should have after all images have loaded.

Now the animate scroll function is scrolling to the top of the relevant div.

Thanks all for your efforts to help

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla way

```js
var el = document.getElementById('myelement');
el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight;
```